# memory leak in hiredis using valgrind

Tags: c, memory-leaks, redis, hiredis

I ran valgrind on my code which uses hiredis, it points out the following individual lines in my code :

- redisAsyncConnect()
- redisAsyncConnectUnix()
- redisLibuvAttach()
- uv_loop_new()

I have used 'redisAsyncDisconnect' to free up the memory for the first two cases, couldn't find the right method for third one. For the fourth one i used uv_stop(). But still valgrind says there is definitely a loss in memory in all the four, what is the right way to release the memory ?

Comment: I believe you tried `redisLibuvDetach()` ? :)

Comment: @Eregrith for all the three ?

Comment: No, just as a pair for `redisLibuv*Attach*()`

Comment: i dont think there is a method like that

Answer (score 1):

Just doing [a simple google search](https://www.google.fr/search?q=how%20to%20free%20redisLibuvAttach%28%29) shows the method `redisLibuvAttach()` [just does a simple malloc](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/deps/hiredis/adapters/libuv.h)

```
static int redisLibuvAttach(redisAsyncContext* ac, uv_loop_t* loop) {
  redisContext *c = &(ac->c);

  if (ac->ev.data != NULL) {
    return REDIS_ERR;
  }

  ac->ev.addRead  = redisLibuvAddRead;
  ac->ev.delRead  = redisLibuvDelRead;
  ac->ev.addWrite = redisLibuvAddWrite;
  ac->ev.delWrite = redisLibuvDelWrite;
  ac->ev.cleanup  = redisLibuvCleanup;

  redisLibuvEvents* p = (redisLibuvEvents*)malloc(sizeof(*p));

  if (!p) {
    return REDIS_ERR;
  }

  m emset(p, 0, sizeof(*p));

  if (uv_poll_init(loop, &p->handle, c->fd) != 0) {
    return REDIS_ERR;
  }

  ac->ev.data    = p;
  p->handle.data = p;
  p->context     = ac;

  return REDIS_OK;
}
```

The method `on_close` in that file shows you can simply `free(handle->data)` :

```
static void on_close(uv_handle_t* handle) {
  redisLibuvEvents* p = (redisLibuvEvents*)handle->data;

  free(p);
}
```

Or just make sure that method is called.

Comment: all that i have is a pointer to redisAsyncContext, using redisAsyncDisconnect() gives a segmentation fault and redisFree() works but shows up as memory lost in valgrind. Is there any hiredis function to release to properly ?